# build directory with Makefile - compiles everytime

Tags: makefile

I have 3 files in my directory as follows:

```
foo.h
foo.cc
main.cc
build/ <-- Created if doesn't exist.
```

I want the `.o` and executable files to be generated in a `build` folder in the same directory.

I also don't want the code recompiling if nothing has changed.

Here is my Makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-std=c++17
OBJS=build/foo.o

.PHONY: all clean

all: build/main

build/main: main.cc $(OBJS)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

build/%.o: %.cc build
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

build:
  mkdir -p build

clean:
  rm -rf build
```

If I run `make build/foo.o`, it doesn't re-compile if nothing has changed in the source code.

But `make all` or `make build/main` always re-compiles everything. What am I doing wrong?

I don't have this issue if I output the compiled code in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, just minutes after posting this, I found the [answer on Google](https://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/making-directories-gnu-make).

Problem is that because the `build` directory timestamp gets updated even if one file in the directory is created/updated, it will rebuild always from scratch.

There are several approaches listed in the link above to fix it. I ended up just adding a pipe (`|`) operator to the `build` rule to make it an order-only pre-requisite. i.e. this line:

```
build/%.o: %.cc |build
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

and that seems to have fixed it :|